# Distinguish between class members and arguments with same name in VBA?

Tags: vba, class, parameters, arguments, member

Ist there a way to distinguish between class members and property/sub/function arguments with same name in VBA? For example:

Class1:

```vb
Private Name As String

Property Let LastName(Name As String)
   this.Name = Name
End Property

Property Get LastName() As String
    Dim Name As String
    Name = "Mr. "
    LastName = Name & this.Name
End Property
```

In other languages you can use the keyword `this` to reference to a class/instance(?) member. But how is it in VBA solved? I know you could use to different names. But that is not what I want.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sometimes there are rules (or your code won't compile), some other times there are coding conventions: say what you're trying to do here would work, the code wouldn't follow VBA conventions and other developers would have a hard time reading it. I would suggest you stick to the convention and use different names (`pProperty` for internal variables and `Property` for members)

Comment: The `Me` keyword in VBA serve the same purpose as the `this` keyword in other languages.

Comment: Mostly in VBA private member variables in a class start with `m_` like `Private m_name As String`. Common convention for private variable and for parameter names: it should not start with capital letter. And the parameter of the property `LastName` could be named e.g. like `newName`. Here about what [Me-Keyword](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008868)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a This with a Type like Mathieu teaches us in [private-this-as-tsomething](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/04/25/private-this-as-tsomething/)

Just create a Type with the vars and assign it to This.

```vb
Private Type TPerson
  Name As String
End Type

Private This As TPerson
Property Let LastName(Name As String)
   This.Name = Name
End Property

Property Get LastName() As String
    Dim Name As String
    Name = "Mr. "
    LastName = Name & This.Name
End Property
```

Don't forget to read the other articles on RubberDuckVBA as they provide many great insights to VBA-OOP.

Comment: This a nice workaround which needs constantly just three lines of code more. Thanks for this solution and the hint at RubberDuckVBA.

Comment: The 'This' concept can be extended.  I prefer to use two Types, 'Properties' and 'State' where properties is used to house the private variables behind getters and setters and State is used for private variables which represent the internal state of the object instance.  I then define the private variables p and s respectively.   thus I can have a getter and setter called FirstName and a backing variable which stores the value as p.FirstName etc

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, keyword to use instead of `this.` is `Me.` However this throws a compile error if the variable referenced inside the class is private (I am not sure why). A possible workaround is to change it to public.

```
''''  Class1
Private PrName As String
Public PbName As String

Property Let LastName(Name As String)
   Me.PrName = Name ' throws a compile error
   Me.PbName = Name ' OK
End Property
```

UPDATE:
You could also create extra layer of wrapper functions / properties - `set_name` and `getName`. The `Name` variable then wouldn't require renaming or change of scope. Also the input parameters of the original properties are left intact.

```
Private Name As String

Property Let LastName(Name As String)
   Call set_name(Name) ' throws a compile error
End Property

Private Sub set_name(new_name As String)
    ' wrapper
    Name = new_name
End Sub

Property Get getName() As String
    ' wrapper
    getName = Name
End Property

Property Get LastName() As String
    Dim Name As String
    Name = "Mr. "
    LastName = Name & Me.getName
End Property
```

Comment: Yes, I've realized it also, that `Public` with `Me` works. But `Public` is not a workaround for me since there is no encapsulation. So it seem that I'm not alone with this problem :) Thanks

Comment: If the variable is private you don,t need to prefix with Me. The default action is to use the name from the class. If you have the same name in another class then you need to qualify the name with the class name.

Comment: @Asg definitely not alone, this is a tricky one.. You might want to check my updated answer, I believe this might be the solution you need.

Comment: Wrapper is a solution but it makes the code IMHO a little massy. I didn't know that VBA lacks in this point. Thanks again.